# Google Spreadsheet IE error using ajax

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull in data from a specific cell into my webpage using jquery/ajax.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsVuHqMG8OuHdDEtdWxUMUxjTUR4R3BPNFk0S25TcFE&range=d4&output=csv",
success:function(result) {
alert(result);
}
});
```

This is working fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but nothing is happending in IE9 and below and I don't know why. The console isn't throwing any errors either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pasted the url into IE10, downloaded as a CSV file just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use a standard AJAX request against the URL you are using. That URL will redirect you a few times until you are given a downloadable file, not one that you can retrieve data from.

I would suggest looking at the ["Simple example of retrieving JSON feeds from Spreadsheets Data API"](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample) documentation as this does provide you with be able to retrieve your data from a GSS as JSON.

Basically ...

You first add a javascript file your website as follows...

```
<script src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/*ID*/*WS*/public/values?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=*FN*"></script>
```

• Where ****ID**** is the spreadsheet's long ID.

• Where ****WS**** is the worksheet number e.g. 1,2,3 etc.

• Where ****FN**** is the function you want to call.

Then with the callback function you can do what ever you want with it, for example.

```
function callBackFunc(json){

   // Loop through all returned data
   for(i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++;){

      // Each row of data
      entry = json.feed.entry[i];

      // Each cell is called gsx$ CELL HEADING .$t;
      cell1 = entry.gsx$firstCellHeading.$t;
      cell2 = entry.gsx$blahblahblah.$t;

   }
}
```

I use this method to populate a lot of information to our company's website, as we don't have a CMS and it allows any member staff to update information on the website using a GSS that they have been given permissions to edit.

**EDIT**

I also forgot to mention that the above method also gets around any cross domain issues that IE 9 and below have issues with, so there's no need to worry about CORS and having to convert to XDR for IE.

On the plus side XHR is supported in IE 10 :) can't wait for that to be come the norm and IE9 to fade out.